# ASP MVC 5 selectedrow linked webGrids

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have nested list object in a view:
mainlist
 ListA
 ListB
 ListC

in a view. Basically, in the controller, I have an object with other objects as members

I created webGrid (grid1) using the data in ListA

I want to create a conditional webGrid (grid2) based on the row selected in grid1, dynamically (e.g.; grid2 content changes when grid1 selected row change)

I tried something kike this

```
@{
   if(grid1.HasSelection){
     var aVar = grid1.SelectedRow["aColumn"]
     grid2Rows = from g in mainlist.ListB
                 where g.aColumn == aVar
                 select g;
     //build webgrid2 here
     .
     .   
   }
}
```

But the firing does not happen.  when the page comes up, nothing is selected in grid1, hence the if condition is bypassed.

Is there a way to get a firing event on selected row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your razor view is rendered once on the server. Are you posting the selected value in grid1 back to the server at any point?  If not then the view will never be re-rendered.

There are two common approaches to solving this type of issue.

You can render all possible values in the view and use javascript to show and hide values in the onChange event for grid1 or you can make an AJAX call back to the server and return a partial view.

Comment: Hi ... thanks.  I will go with the 2nd suggestion "or you can make an AJAX call back to the server and return a partial view.".   I appreciate your help.